# Django: Reverse for 'download_excel/309' not found. 'download_excel/309' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on designing a Django app that would allow a person to download an excel with data from a page. I am trying to connect a hyperlink to a view function but it keeps returning the reverse match. I am able to go directly to the url and it downloads the excel but when I can't load the index.html file because of the error. Am I naming the hyperlink wrong?

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('Excel/<int:study>', views.Excel, name='Excel'),
    path('download_excel/<int:study>', views.download_excel, name='download_excel'),
]
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <title>Download File</title>
</head>
<body>
<enter>
  <h1>Download File using Django</h1>
  <a href="{% url 'polls:download_excel/309' %}">Download State Impulsivity Excel</a>
</enter>  
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
def download_excel(request, study):
    with BytesIO() as b:
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(b, engine='xlsxwriter')
        Retrieve(study)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        writer.save()
        Names(study)
        filename = str(name) + "_" + str(current_time) + ".xlsx"
        response = HttpResponse(
            b.getvalue(),
            content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
        )
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
        return response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because Django thinks 'download_excel/309' is the whole name of your view.  The view name and its positional argument(s) should be separated, so instead of this:

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:download_excel/309' %}">
```

...you should do something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:download_excel' '309' %}">
```

This will generate a URL in your code that looks like:

```
<a href="/download_excel/309/"> etc...
```

One last note - Django will automatically append a trailing `/` slash to the end of your URL, but it's a best practice to do this explicitly.  So instead of:

```
path('download_excel/<int:study>', views.download_excel, name='download_excel')
```

Do this:

```
path('download_excel/<int:study>/', views.download_excel, name='download_excel')
```

Note the slash after `<int:study>`.